# std::vector to java.util.Vector code generation with swig

Tags: java, c++, list, vector, swig

I try to generate java code with SWIG

In **MyList.h** I declared a custom list object called **_list**

```
List<T*> _list;
```

and this List class inherits from vector

```
class List : public vector<T>
```

In a business class (in C++) I return a List of custom objects

```
List<MyObject> getMyList(){
   ....
   return list;
}
```

so I want to generate java code where I can retrieve this C++ List as java.util.List or java.util.Vector.

in my swig.i file I couldn't manage how to embody

```
%typemap(jstype) List "java.util.Vector"
namespace std {
   %template(CustomVector) vector<MyObject>;
}
```

any kind help how to configure this swig.i template file or some sample code to generate a java.util.List / Vector returning function will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854335/how-to-create-a-java-class-similar-to-a-c-template-class

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462297/how-to-use-classt-in-java

Comment: Concerning the `std::vector` inheritance, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector).

Comment: OK let's say I won't use/return a std::vector then how can I transfer a list of objects from c++ layer to my java layer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SWIG (v1.3.29) generated C++ to Java Vector class not acting properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145605/swig-v1-3-29-generated-c-to-java-vector-class-not-acting-properly)

Comment: I think my answer on that question covers `std::vector` -> Java `Collection` in sufficient detail. If it's not let me know and I'll take a look later this week.

Comment: thanks awoodland actually your answer is great,helpful.But i got a little confused when I try to do the same with generic types

Comment: @BeratOnurErsen ok, that makes sense. I'll write a generalisation of that up as an answer at some point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't really want to be touching `java.util.Vector` with your wrapped interfaces because you will end up duplicating storage or making large numbers of copy operations every time you pass it in/out of a function. (Note also that in general in C++ inhering from containers is odd design).

Instead in Java the "right" thing to do is to inherit from `java.util.AbstractList`. This answer is a more generic version of my [older answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8190135/168175).

It works for all `std::vector` types, not just a fixed type and handles [primitives which need to be accessed via Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types) using an "autobox" custom type map. It's missing support for the specialized `std::vector<bool>`, but that should be simple to add if you need it.

```
%{
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
%}

%include <stdint.i>
%include <std_except.i>

namespace std {

    template<class T> class vector {
      public:
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef const value_type& const_reference;
        vector();
        vector(size_type n);
        vector(const vector& o);
        size_type capacity() const;
        void reserve(size_type n);
        %rename(isEmpty) empty;
        bool empty() const;
        void clear();
        void push_back(const value_type& x);
        %extend {
            const_reference get(int i) const throw (std::out_of_range) {
                return $self->at(i);
            }
            value_type set(int i, const value_type& VECTOR_VALUE_IN) throw (std::out_of_range) {
                const T old = $self->at(i);
                $self->at(i) = VECTOR_VALUE_IN;
                return old;
            }
            int32_t size() const {
              return $self->size();
            }
            void removeRange(int32_t from, int32_t to) {
              $self->erase($self->begin()+from, $self->begin()+to);
            }
        }
    };
}

// Java typemaps for autoboxing in return types of generics
%define AUTOBOX(CTYPE, JTYPE)
%typemap(autobox) CTYPE, const CTYPE&, CTYPE& "JTYPE"
%enddef
AUTOBOX(double, Double)
AUTOBOX(float, Float)
AUTOBOX(boolean, Boolean)
AUTOBOX(signed char, Byte)
AUTOBOX(short, Short)
AUTOBOX(int, Integer)
AUTOBOX(long, Long)
AUTOBOX(SWIGTYPE, $typemap(jstype,$1_basetype))

%typemap(javabase) std::vector "java.util.AbstractList<$typemap(autobox,$1_basetype::value_type)>"
%typemap(javainterface) std::vector "java.util.RandomAccess"
%typemap(jstype) std::vector get "$typemap(autobox,$1_basetype)"
%typemap(jstype) std::vector set "$typemap(autobox,$1_basetype)"
%typemap(jstype) std::vector &VECTOR_VALUE_IN "$typemap(autobox,$1_basetype)"
%typemap(javacode) std::vector %{
  $javaclassname(java.util.Collection<$typemap(autobox,$1_basetype::value_type)> e) {
    this.reserve(e.size());
    for($typemap(autobox,$1_basetype::value_type) value: e) {
      this.push_back(value);
    }
  }
%}
```

Most of this is fairly similar to the default std_vector.i that SWIG currently provides, the new bits are the renaming, extending and typemaps that extend `AbstractList` and implement `RandomAccess`. It also adds a constructor that takes other `Collection`s - this is recommended by the Java documentation and easy enough to do. (There's an overload for other `std::vector` types which is *much* faster).

I tested this vector wrapping within another SWIG interface:

```
%module test

%include "vector.i"

%template(DblVec) std::vector<double>;
%template(ByteVec) std::vector<signed char>;
%include <std_string.i>
%template(StringVec) std::vector<std::string>;

%inline %{
struct foo {};
%}

%template(FooVec) std::vector<foo>;
```

Which I was able to compile and run with:

```
public class run {
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    DblVec dv = new DblVec(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      dv.set(i,(double)i);
    }
    FooVec fv = new FooVec(1);
    fv.set(0, new foo());
    for (double d: dv) {
      System.out.println(d);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Would you still recommend using this wrapper instead of SWIG's `std_vector.i` implementation? I just need to exchange primitive array data in my case. Thanks!

Comment: @JesúsZazueta if it's just an array of primitives I'd probably just use the JNI arrays interface to do it and take the hit on a copy or two. (Or re-work the code so that it can use a borrowed buffer from Java and share the same memory).

Comment: @Flexo you are the SWIG GOD ! Thx!

Comment: FYI this functionality is likely to get included in SWIG 3.1 when released.

Comment: Typemapping autoboxed types seems not to work any more on 3.0. It may no longer match the pattern. Trying this code verbatim does not work.

Comment: @jason I'd skip to SWIG 3.1 if you can and use that. It should all just work there out the box now, because a variant of the same idea got merged into it: https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/std_vector.i, which uses the new jboxtype typemap: https://github.com/swig/swig/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jboxtype&type=