# std::vector< int64_t> trduced from c++ to java returns SWIGTYPE_p_in64_t which is unusable

Tags: java, vector, swig, int64

I am trying to use swig (v3) to transform a function which have a std::vector as entry to a java code. but when compiling with swig, I got a file with a class StdVector_int64 with a method get(int i) that returns a SWIGTYPE_p_in64_t.... which is unusable. so my question is how to transform SWIGTYPE_p_in64_t.java to primitive java type?

I made a tools.swig file with template directive but it does not work as needed.

the c++ header file :

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include "stdint.h"

extern void computeVector(std::vector<int64_t> _return);
```

the swig file :

```
%module(directors="1") LocalServices 
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "stdint.i"

%{
#include "tools.h"
using namespace cov::core;
%}

%template(StdVector_int64) std::vector< in64_t >;

%javaconst(1);

%include "tools.h"
```

the command launched :

```
swig -c++ -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -java tools.swig
```

I want the StdVector_int64's get(...) method to return a long primitive type.

Comment: You're probably going to have a lot more success if you add a wrapper API that can accept a bare array to write the result into. You aren't going to be able to marshal a `std::vector` across in a meaningful way. It sounds like what you want on the Java side is just a `long[]`, and so you'll have the best success if you use an array type on the C++ side.

Comment: vector is similar to ArrayList, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596052/stdvector-to-java-util-vector-code-generation-with-swig)

Comment: I can not use other thing than vector for some internal reasons.

Comment: You have a typo in `%template(StdVector_int64) std::vector< in64_t >;` - `in64_t` should be `int64_t`. Having a public interface that takes a vector by value is going to cause lots of problems besides this though.

Comment: @Flexo it was juste an example. the real interface has const& parameter :o)

Comment: Ok, but when I fix that your example works as is, so I'm a little confused now.

Comment: Ok, the problem came from generated swig files which conflict... manual swig files works, not the generated ones....